# Can't change value of global variable JS

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have 2 global variables : Lon and Lat
And I want to change the value of these variables inside the function of geolocalisation offered by HTML5:
here is my code :

```
window.lat={{geo['latitude']}};
window.lon={{geo['longitude']}};
var SK= readCookie('SK');
if(SK==1)
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e){
    window.lat=e.coords.latitude;
    window.lon=e.coords.longitude;
    window.zoomi=15;
    })
}
```

the final value of window .lat is always

```
window.lat={{geo['latitude']}}
```

Does anyone know why ?

PS: the SK==1 is true, and inside the function(e), I tried to alert the values and they really change.
but once out of the function, everything vanishes

Comment: What function?  (You haven't defined one in this code.)  Where/when is the function called?

Comment: function(e), the callback

Comment: What is `window.lat = {{ ... }}`??

Comment: Ah, now I see it.  Is the callback being executed?  When you debug this, what is `window.lat` before the statement in the callback, and what is it after?  A simple assignment like that should work, so I still suspect that the call isn't happening.  In what way do you test it?

Comment: the {{...}} is Twig Syntax , Sorry I didn't mention it!

Comment: before Window.lat takes the PHP Value geo['latitude'] in the callback I alert it and it gives me the correct value of HTML5 latitude 
after that it goes back to the PHP value .. 
Let's say :
Lat = 32;
Then Lat = 32,000096544;
then Lat = 32 ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is always synchronous and single-threaded so if you are checking window.lat after callback it gets executed even before gelocation call and it has same value.geolocation takes few seconds to get the value and you must write up your code in callback fucntion or write a function to use geolcoation values.

```
window.lat=1;
window.lon=3;
var SK= 1
if(SK==1)
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

}


//anything written here will be executed before even the getCurrentPosition retuns or sets the results

function showPosition(position)
{
     alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +  "-Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude); 
    //write your code here to use the location 
}
```

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xa64Q/ explaining the issue if we are running alert after few seconds it returns correct value

Comment: You're correct, but do you suggest the assignment should be after some time (5 seconds)?

Comment: nope you should do whatever you are trying to do in callback function or create a series of callback functions so that you never miss the assignment call

Comment: here is what you can do i think navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
  var gps = (position.coords.latitude+position.coords.longitude); 
  window.GlobalVar = gps;

  continueSomeProcess();
});

function continueSomeProcess() {
  // this code will be able to access window.GlobalVar
'}

Comment: I've found another turn around, I didn't mention that I'm using Google maps API, so the thing that I did was refreshing the map once I get the data from HTML5. I don't know if it's best practice but It worked .. 
Eitherway, your answer was the most accurate and defined the problem 
Thanks ! +1 and Mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Step through it with a debugger (like Chrome dev tools or Firebug for Firefox). This code works and is the same in principle. It works just fine for this sort of variable assignment:

```
window.x = 1;
function change() {
 window.x = 2;   
}
change();
alert(window.x);
```

My guess is that the `getCurrentPosition` call is abruptly failing. BTW, that call takes an error call back handler so you should define one for your code.